# Python - how to clear class variables automatically when class variables are resource

Tags: python, resources, xlwings

I have a problem with dealing with class variables in Python. I have a code as the following.

```
class TempClass:
    resource = xlwings.Book() # xlwings is a library manipulating Excel file.

    #...
```

Here, to clear 'resource', I need to execute

```
resource.close()
```

Is there any built-in function called when a class (not object) is cleared, so that I can write the above code in that function? Or is there any way to clear 'resource'?

My Python version is 3.6

Comment: What do you mean, when a class is "cleared"?

Comment: My guess is you are talking about when you override the data of (an object of?) tempclass. What you could do is create a method in temp class that first does resource.close() and then sets the object to whatever the input method is, and use this instead of then normal obj = (new thing).

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a class instead of an instance? You could more easily use a context manager with an instance. See [**`closing`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) for example

Comment: @OwenCummings So you mean making an instance which is not used by user? I think it is great idea!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a class variable. A class variable is alive as long as the class exists probably as long as your python interpreter isn't shutdown.

Normally with ressources that need to be closed you can simply use a contextmanager (for example [`contextlib.closing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing)):

```
import contextlib

# I don't have xlwings so I create some class that acts like it:
class Book(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('init')

    def close(self):
        print('close')
```

The actual "context" can be created and used like this. Inside the block the resource is alive and it's closed after the block ends. I use `print`s to show where each method is called:

```
print('before the context')
with contextlib.closing(Book()):
    print('inside the context')
print('after the context')
```

Which prints:

```
before the context
init
inside the context
close
after the context
```

Comment: Hmm...but if I use "contextlib", I need to write all the code that using "Book" inside "with" scope. Actually, in my code, all the 'TempClass' instances use 'resource' until my program is shut down.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't leave file handles open until the program shuts down. Most of the time you only need it in very few parts and these can be easily put into a context manager.

Comment: @YounghoonJeong yes, everything would happen within the `with` scope. Put the block in a function and pass the `Book` as a parameter.